# Union of two sharepoint list in SSRS

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have requirement to union two sharepoint list on basis of common id field for showing report. Please suggest whether union operation is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean UNION in the SQL sense (appending together) or you mean you want to join the two lists on a common value.

There's no way to append datasets together inside a report, but there is some limited functionality to look up the values from a dataset based on a value in another dataset.

Take a look at these report expression functions:

[Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ee210531.aspx)

[LookupSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ee240819.aspx)

Comment: By Union I mean appending two lists. I have two identical lists which I want to combine and show toghether.

Comment: As noted above there isn't a way to do this inside a report.